# SQL Server 2016 data type conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query. I am using multiple SELECT statements as the tool I am working with requires the FROM clause in the first line with a single SELECT value, for some reason.

DOCUMENT_ID is an integer type column. I need the DOCUMENT_IDs as a comma separated values, as the output from this query. (Ex. 1234,7786, 6478, 5835)

The problem is that I am running into the below error. Can someone please help.

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.
I read some post regarding using converting to NVARCHAR using CAST, however I am running into syntax errors doing the same. Where exactly could it be applied?

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_ID FROM (
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + em.DOCUMENT_ID 
        FROM(
            SELECT distinct a.DOCUMENT_ID AS DOCUMENT_ID FROM A_DOCUMENT a
            inner join PRICE_RECORD wk ON a.DOCUMENT_ID = wk.DOCUMENT_ID
            WHERE a.APPROVAL_STATUS = 'Submitted'
            ) em
        ORDER BY em.DOCUMENT_ID FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, '') AS DOCUMENT_ID
) AS Output
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `DOCUMENT_ID` is an `int` then replace `',' + em.DOCUMENT_ID` with one of the following:

```
CONCAT(',', em.DOCUMENT_ID) --SQL Server 2012+
',' + CONVERT(varchar(10),em.DOCUMENT_ID)
--Or, if you prefer CAST
',' + CAST(em.DOCUMENT_ID AS varchar(10))
```

`int` has a higher [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) than a `varchar`, therefore your comma (`','`) was being implicity converted to an `int`, which was causing a conversion error.

Comment: Thank you very much Larnu. Appreciate your quick help. My code works now.